# Integration by parts disconnect

Tags: statistics, integration

I'm trying to integrate $\displaystyle E(Y^2) = \int^\infty_0 y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$
doing it by parts this is my logic.

$\displaystyle E(Y^2) = \int^\infty_0 y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$ where $u=y^2$, $du=2y\,dy$, $dv=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\, dy$ and $v = -e^{-\lambda y}$ solving by parts we get $\displaystyle (y^2)(-e^{-\lambda y})-\int^\infty_0 -e^{-\lambda y} 2y \,dy$ which then simplifies to $\displaystyle 0 + 2\int^\infty_0y e^{-\lambda y} dy$ which is the same as $0 + 2 E(Y) = \dfrac{2}{\lambda}$ where $E(Y)=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$

however the solutions shows a different answer of $\dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}$ can someone explain why this is?
http://oi40.tinypic.com/b5fwxs.jpg

Comment: Your $E(Y)$ is incorrect.

Comment: Check on your integral that equals 1/λ, I believe if you perform integration by parts on the integral it will yield 1/(λ^2).

Comment: $E(Y)$ would be $\int_0^\infty y\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dy$

Comment: yes i solved for E(Y) and it is definitely $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ you can also see in the solutions(link) they use $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for E(Y) as well, whats confusing is on line  5 i dont know how they got the $\frac{2}{\lambda}$ where i think it should only be 2

Comment: @notamathwiz $E(Y)=1/\lambda$ but $\int_0^\infty ye^{-\lambda y}\,\mathrm{d}y=1/\lambda\,E(Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating by parts, take $u= y^2 \Rightarrow du= 2y \cdot dy$ and $dv=e^{-\lambda y} \Rightarrow v = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}.$

$$\begin{align}
\int y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy & = \lambda \int y^2 e^{-\lambda y} dy \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{y^2e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda} - \int \frac{2y e^{-\lambda y}}{(-\lambda)} dy\right] \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-y^2e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} + \color{red}{\frac{2}{\lambda}\int ye^{-\lambda y} dy}\right]. \\
\end{align}$$

Integrating the red colored by parts again, let $u= y \Rightarrow du= dy$ and $dv=e^{-\lambda y} \Rightarrow v = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda}.$
$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\frac{2}{\lambda}\int ye^{-\lambda y} dy}
& = \frac{2}{\lambda} \left[\frac{ye^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda} - \int \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{(-\lambda)} dy \right] \\
& = \frac{2}{\lambda} \left[\frac{-ye^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} + \int \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} dy \right] \\
& = \frac{2}{\lambda} \left[\frac{-ye^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} + \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{(-\lambda)\lambda} dy \right] \\
& = \color{blue}{\frac{2}{\lambda} \left[\frac{-ye^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} - \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda^2} \right]}.
\end{align}$$

Put the blue part back, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\int y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy 
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-y^2e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} + \color{red}{\frac{2}{\lambda}\int ye^{-\lambda y} dy}\right] \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-y^2e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} + \color{blue}{\frac{2}{\lambda} \left[\frac{-ye^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda} - \dfrac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda^2} \right]}\right] \\
& = e^{-\lambda y} \left(-y^2 - \frac{2y}{\lambda} - \frac{2}{\lambda^2} \right).
\end{align}$$

Therefore
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy  
& = \left[e^{-\lambda y} \left(-y^2 -\frac{2y}{\lambda} - \frac{2}{\lambda^2} \right) \right]_0^\infty \\
& = 0 - \left(- \dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}\right) \\
& = \dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$E(Y^2) = \int^\infty_0 y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$$

Lets use Integration by Parts to do the indefinite integral and then we'll the limits of integration.

We have:

$$\int y^2\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy = \lambda \int y^2 e^{-\lambda y} dy$$

using IBP, we let:

- $u = y^2 \rightarrow du = 2 y dy$
- $v = e^{-\lambda y} dy \rightarrow = -\dfrac{1}{\lambda e^{\lambda y}}$

So, we have:

$$2 \int \dfrac{y}{e^{\lambda y}} dy-\dfrac{y^2}{e^{\lambda y}}$$

Repeating this process, we have:

- $u = y \rightarrow  du = dy$
- $dv = e^{-(\lambda y)}  dy \rightarrow v = -\dfrac{1}{\lambda e^{\lambda y}}$

So, we have:

$$-\dfrac{y^2}{e^{\lambda y}}-\dfrac{2 y}{\lambda e^{\lambda y}}+\dfrac{2 \int e^{-\lambda y}  dy}{\lambda}$$

This is equal to:

$$ -\dfrac{e^{-\lambda y} (\lambda^2 y^2+2 \lambda y+2)}{\lambda^2}+ \text{constant}$$

Over the limits of integration $(0 , \infty)$, we see that this yields:

$$\dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}$$

Comment: Kill the integral Amzoti. :-)

Comment: I've felt pretty lazy today...just couldn't get in the "groove"...sounds like you had a full day! ;-)

Comment: post it! If I recall, I think I edited the post earlier today! ;-)

Comment: I'm going to upvote the OP's question, too...As you say, examples are hard to come by, and sometimes an OP may just be lost as to where to start. I wish folks were "gentler" on first-timer/newcomers!

Comment: @amWhy: I totally agree and this problem would have been really hard for new folks to it because it jumps into a system as opposed to the simpler [sic] single system! This is the sort of thing that scares people away from math, instead of people trying to help them feel like they can, it is rather tearing them down and making them feel worse - so, I totally agree with you!